# In Flutter, how do I show a SnackBar from a platform call handler?

Tags: flutter

SnackBars in Flutter usually seem pretty easy, but they do not show up when trying to show them from within a `Channel`'s `methodCallHandler`. Does anyone know why?

Here's a stripped down version of my code (just the relevant parts):

```dart
class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _channel.setMethodCallHandler(_handlePlatformMessages);
  }

  void _onExampleButtonPressed(BuildContext context) {
    // This correctly shows my SnackBar if I use this as an 
    // onPressed handler from a button
    _showGeneralError(); 
  }

  Future<Null> _handlePlatformMessages(MethodCall call) async {
    // ... (omitted for clarity) ...
    if (!successful) {
      _showGeneralError(); // Does not show a SnackBar :(
    }
  }

  void _showGeneralError() {
    var snackBar = new SnackBar(
        content: new Text(Strings.of(context).generalError()),
        backgroundColor: Palette.yellow
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: /* some widgets */;
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: using a GlobalKey as per Remi's comment. This didn't fix the issue though.

Comment: I don't know what the actual problem is. But don't use `_scaffoldContext` this way. It's anti-pattern and may lead to potential problems. If needed instead wrap your stateful widget inside a `Scaffold`. Or use `GlobalKey`.

Comment: Ah cool, thanks for the tip

Comment: It's not clear if using `GlobalKey` has actually fixed your problem or not. Could you clarify, and if it did maybe add an answer yourself (if Remi doesn't want to) explaining what you did so that this isn't open any more?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it did not fix it. I'll clarify in the edit comment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution for this was to delay sending the message from the platform code by a bit. It must have been sent too soon or something (even though the code was being handled on the flutter side). I delayed the message by a single frame by posting the message to the main thread handler on Android.